# I am unable to open mred-designer

Tags: racket

In DrRacket, 
I just installed mred-designer from File->install package menu.

but I can't find any method to open this mred-designer.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#lang racket
(require mred-designer)
```

sorry I missed this simple attempt

(require mred-designer) was the solution